# Optaplanner: How to write pickup before delivery constraint using java stream api

Tags: java, java-stream, optaplanner

Can any one help me how to write pick up before delivery constraint using java stream api
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgUjX.png). [screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlvuF.png)

```
rule "pickupBeforeDelivery"
    when
        Visit(visitType == VisitType.PICKUP, $ride : ride, $vehicle : vehicle, $pickupVisitIndex : visitIndex)
        Visit(ride == $ride, visitType == VisitType.DELIVERY, vehicle == $vehicle, visitIndex < $pickupVisitIndex, $deliveryVisitIndex : visitIndex)
    then
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, - ($pickupVisitIndex - $deliveryVisitIndex));
end
```

using stream api

```
  return factory.from(TimeWindowedPlanningVisit.class)
                .filter(timeWindowedPlanningVisit -> timeWindowedPlanningVisit.getVisitType()==VisitType.PICKUP)
                .filter(timeWindowedPlanningVisit -> timeWindowedPlanningVisit.getRide().getDeliveryVisit().getVisitIndex() < timeWindowedPlanningVisit.getVisitIndex() &&
                        timeWindowedPlanningVisit.getVehicle() == timeWindowedPlanningVisit.getRide().deliveryVisit.getVehicle())
                .penalizeLong("pickup before delivery",
                        BendableLongScore.ofSoft(2, 1, 0, 1),
                        x -> (x.getVisitIndex() - x.getRide().getDeliveryVisit().getVisitIndex() ));
```

Comment: Pickup before delivery on the normal VRP model won't work efficiently. For what it is worth, you need to do something like this https://github.com/ge0ffrey/optaplanner-mixedvrp-experiment which worked very well but that currently has a regression.

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey De Smet, Yes. previously we have normal VRP Solution with time windowed and vehicle capacity constraints with java based configurations(not xml&. drl file), now i am trying to add pick up before delivery, pick up & delivery by the same vehicle constraints using constraints stream api by following the above link shared by you.

Comment: i am facing following exception after adding the pick up before delivery constraints java.lang.IllegalStateException: The entity (Visit-8463) has a variable (previousStandstill) with value (Visit-8462) which has a sourceVariableName variable (nextPlanningVisit) with a value (Visit-8461) which is not null. Verify the consistency of your input problem for that sourceVariableName variable.

Comment: Exactly, that's the regression in that codebase that we wrote for a customer. We haven't got the priority/bandwidth to look at it currently. But after VRP simplification we should get back to it one day and clean up and make it part of optaplanner-quickstarts.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a DRL, turning it into a Constraint Stream is fairly straight-forward. Just follow the logic of the rule.

First, you have:

```
Visit(visitType == VisitType.PICKUP, ...)
```

This naturally translates to:

```
factory.from(Visit.class)
    .filter(visit -> visitType == VisitType.PICKUP)
```

Then, the DRL follows:

```
Visit(ride == $ride, vehicle == $vehicle, visitIndex < $pickupVisitIndex, ...)
```

This then has to become a `join` with several joiners:

```
.join(Visit.class,
    Joiners.equal(Visit::getRide),
    Joiners.equal(Visit::getVehicle),
    Joiners.greaterThan(Visit::visitIndex))
```

Of course this second `Visit` can only be a `DELIVERY`, so you add another filter:

```
.filter((pickup, delivery) -> delivery.getVisitType() == VisitType.DELIVERY)
```

And then finally, all that is left is the consequence. In your case:

```
.penalize("pickup before delivery",
    BendableLongScore.ofSoft(2, 1, 0, 1), // Your choice.
    (pickup, delivery) -> pickup.getVisitIndex() - delivery.getVisitIndex())
```

Putting this all together:

```
factory.from(Visit.class)
    .filter(visit -> visitType == VisitType.PICKUP)
    .join(Visit.class,
        Joiners.equal(Visit::getRide),
        Joiners.equal(Visit::getVehicle),
        Joiners.greaterThan(Visit::visitIndex))
    .filter((pickup, delivery) -> delivery.getVisitType() == VisitType.DELIVERY)
    .penalize("pickup before delivery",
        BendableLongScore.ofSoft(2, 1, 0, 1), // Your choice.
        (pickup, delivery) -> pickup.getVisitIndex() - delivery.getVisitIndex());
```

But we can do better than that in this case. As you can see, the second filter is only applied *after* the join is already produced. That is slightly inefficient, as the join will first spend time retrieving all the matching pairs of Visits, only to throw away some of them later. The solution to that is to use a join with a nested stream:

```
factory.from(Visit.class)
    .filter(visit -> visitType == VisitType.PICKUP)
    .join(
        factory.from(Visit.class)
             .filter(visit -> visit.getVisitType() == VisitType.DELIVERY), // Nested stream.
        Joiners.equal(Visit::getRide),
        Joiners.equal(Visit::getVehicle),
        Joiners.greaterThan(Visit::visitIndex))
    .penalize("pickup before delivery",
        BendableLongScore.ofSoft(2, 1, 0, 1), // Your choice.
        (pickup, delivery) -> pickup.getVisitIndex() - delivery.getVisitIndex());
```

This way, the nested stream will be filtered first and the join will only happen after that - ensuring that no performance is wasted creating pairs that will not be used.

Comment: Note: I had to update my answer several times, as the original one was slightly incorrect in the way it handled Joiners.

Comment: Thank you so much @Lukáš Petrovický for the quick response.
added above snippet code to my project, i got the below compile time errors
Cannot resolve method 'join(org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.uni.UniConstraintStream<Visit>, org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.bi.BiJoiner<A,A>, org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.bi.BiJoiner<A,A>, org.optaplanner.core.api.score.stream.bi.BiJoiner<A,A>)'

Answer (score 0):

@Lukáš Petrovický
i changed as below

```
 factory.from(Visit.class)
                .filter(visit -> visit.getVisitType() == VisitType.PICKUP)
                .join(factory.from(Visit.class)
                                .filter(visit -> visit.getVisitType() == VisitType.DELIVERY)) // Nested stream.)
                .filter((pickupVisit, deliveryVisit) -> pickupVisit.getVehicle()==deliveryVisit.getVehicle()
                        && deliveryVisit.getVisitIndex()< pickupVisit.getVisitIndex())
                .penalize("pickup before delivery",
                        BendableLongScore.ofSoft(2, 1, 0, 1), // Your choice.
                        (pickup, delivery) -> pickup.getVisitIndex() - delivery.getVisitIndex());
```

Comment: I do not understand why it would not compile. It did when I tried in my IDE. That said, your code will work perfectly fine - just be aware that you are losing all performance benefits of indexing, if you replace Joiners with a filter.

Comment: Added screenshots of my code, can you please look into the images.

Comment: The tooltip in the screenshot is hiding an important part of the constraint.

Comment: Sorry, i added one more screenshot

Comment: On the face of it, everything looks OK. The compiler warning looks as if the first Visit and the second Visit were a different type. Physically a different class. How that's possible, I do not know. That said, there is not much more I can do here unless I get access to the actual code.

Comment: Thank you for the your assistance, i will try to resolve the compile time error and will reach you if i not find the error.

Comment: join method allows only two parameters one is UniConstraint<A>, and BiJoiner<A, B> <A,B> 
i found remaining methods with first param as .class
```join(UniConstraintStream<B> otherStream)
join(Class<B> otherClass, BiJoiner<A, B> joiner)
 join(Class<B> otherClass, BiJoiner<A, B> joiner1, BiJoiner<A, B> joiner2)
join(Class<B> otherClass, BiJoiner<A, B> joiner1, BiJoiner<A, B> joiner2,
            BiJoiner<A, B> joiner3)
join(Class<B> otherClass, BiJoiner<A, B> joiner1, BiJoiner<A, B> joiner2,
            BiJoiner<A, B> joiner3, BiJoiner<A, B> joiner4)```